# PreferenceFragmentCompat works while testing but crashes on published app

Tags: android, kotlin, preferencefragment

I have run into a very strange error with PreferenceFragmentCompat. I am splitting my preferences into multiple screens using the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#split_your_hierarchy_into_multiple_screens). This works as expected while testing using AVD and testing using my device connected to Android Studio. However, when I publish the app to the Play Store and run the published version, it crashes each time I try to click on one of the multiple settings. I've confirmed the crash on both Android 8 and 10. I have no idea why it works as expected while testing, but crashes in the published version? I am publishing to a closed alpha track. I've tried using the "send feedback" option on crash to view the crash report, but it is not available in the Play Console so I can't track down what is going on. Below is the code:

```
build.gradle (Module: app)
...
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
...
```

```
MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var settingsButton: ImageButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        settingsButton = findViewById(R.id.settingsButtonMain)
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
            settingsClicked()
        }
        ...
    }

    private fun settingsClicked() {
        val settingsIntent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(settingsIntent)
    }
}
```

```
SettingsActivity.kt

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment(this)).commit()
        supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            if(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
                title = "App Settings"
            }
        }
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        ...
    }

    class SettingsFragment(cont: Context) : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        private var context1: Context = cont

        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }

    class Screen1PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.screen1_preferences, null)
        }
    }

    class Screen2PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.screen2_preferences, null)
        }
    }

    override fun onPreferenceStartFragment(caller: PreferenceFragmentCompat?, pref: Preference): Boolean {
        val args: Bundle = pref.extras
        val fragment: Fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(classLoader, pref.fragment)
        fragment.arguments = args
        fragment.setTargetFragment(caller, 0)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()

        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        if(supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()) {
            return true
        }

        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

```
root_preferences.xml

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="App Settings">
        <Preference
            app:fragment="com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity$Screen1PreferencesFragment"
            app:summary="Multi pref screen1"
            app:title="Screen 1" />

        <Preference
            app:fragment="com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity$Screen2PreferencesFragment"
            app:summary="Multi pref screen2"
            app:title="Screen 2" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

```
screen1_preferences.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="Screen 1">
        <Preference
            android:clickable="false"
            app:enabled="false"
            app:summary="This is screen 1"
            app:title="Screen 1" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

```
screen2_preferences.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="Screen 2">
        <Preference
            android:clickable="false"
            app:enabled="false"
            app:summary="This is screen 2"
            app:title="Screen 2" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

On app publish, Google's auto testers reported the below crash stack trace which may be related:

```
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass (FragmentFactory.java:57)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:8)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:2)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:2)
  at com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity.onPreferenceStartFragment (SettingsActivity.java:2)
  at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onPreferenceTreeClick (PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:8)
  at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick (Preference.java:8)
  at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick (Preference.java:8)
  at androidx.preference.Preference$1.onClick (Preference.java:2)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7140)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7117)
  at android.view.View.access$3500 (View.java:801)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:27351)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at java.lang.Class.classForName (Class.java)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:454)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadClass (FragmentFactory.java:2)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass (FragmentFactory.java:2)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:8)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:2)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:2)
  at com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity.onPreferenceStartFragment (SettingsActivity.java:2)
  at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onPreferenceTreeClick (PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:8)
  at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick (Preference.java:8)
  at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick (Preference.java:8)
  at androidx.preference.Preference$1.onClick (Preference.java:2)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7140)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7117)
  at android.view.View.access$3500 (View.java:801)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:27351)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Edit: For future reference - I was able to get the full error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.TestApp, PID: 20293
    androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$e: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity$Screen1PreferencesFragment: make sure class name exists
        at a.j.d.i.d(:91)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(:546)
        at a.j.d.f.a(:57)
        at a.j.d.m$c.a(:390)
        at com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity.e(:370)
        at a.n.g.q(:407)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.h0(:1192)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.i0(:1166)
        at androidx.preference.Preference$a.onClick(:181)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity$Screen1PreferencesFragment
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at a.j.d.i.c(:47)
        at a.j.d.i.d(:88)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(:546) 
        at a.j.d.f.a(:57) 
        at a.j.d.m$c.a(:390) 
        at com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity.e(:370) 
        at a.n.g.q(:407) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference.h0(:1192) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference.i0(:1166) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference$a.onClick(:181) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity$Screen1PreferencesFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.TestApp-Y6977dm5oijKMZmKaT4_3A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.TestApp-Y6977dm5oijKMZmKaT4_3A==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at a.j.d.i.c(:47) 
        at a.j.d.i.d(:88) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(:546) 
        at a.j.d.f.a(:57) 
        at a.j.d.m$c.a(:390) 
        at com.example.TestApp.SettingsActivity.e(:370) 
        at a.n.g.q(:407) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference.h0(:1192) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference.i0(:1166) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference$a.onClick(:181) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20293 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8607', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Sounds like a minification issue. Have you tried the release APK yourself? Does it crash?

Comment: In build.gradle I added `minifyEnabled false` to the release build type. The APK worked on my phone! I will try to submit it to the Play store and see how things go there. I'm curious what the explanation behind this is any why `minifyEnabled true` can cause problems like this? I would have never guessed this was the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @heX for pointing me in the right direction on this one. To replicate the error in Android Studio AVD, add the following code in `buildTypes` in build.gradle (Module: app)

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Run your app in debug mode and it will display the error when you trip it. **The solution in this particular case is to add the following to the `proguard-rules.pro` file:**

```
-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment { public *; }
```

I'll leave it to someone intelligent who can explain why that works. Alternatively you could set `minifyEnabled false` in the build.gradle if you don't mind losing the benefits of minification.

Comment: The minification process removes classes that are not used. You declare `Screen1PreferencesFragment` but it was never explicitly used in code (as far as I can see in the code that you provided) therefore it got removed by the minification process. You can change the scope of your proguard rule to just keep that fragment class.

Comment: @heX You're exactly right. `Screen1PreferencesFragment` is only called by the `Preference` in `root_preferences.xml`. Could you give me an example of what the proguard rule would look like by limiting the scope to the fragment class? Would I do that within the brackets instead of adding Public?